# I have syntax errors and I am not sure how to fix them

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

On line 4 there is a syntax error and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
def is_prime(num):
  isPrime = True
  for i in range(-1, num, 2):
    if num % i = 0:
      isPrime = False
  return isPrime
def main():
  for i in range(1,101):
    if isPrime(i) == True:
      print(i,"is a prime number")
main()
```

Comment: Please add in taglist the programming language! I suppose it is python.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
if num % i == 0:
...
```

Hello Philip, the line above checks for the equality (`==`), instead of assignment (`=`). We would like to help, but stackoverflow is not a debugging service. Please first read the basics, then search for similar questions, and then ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
num % i = 0
```

`=` is an **assignment**.

You are assigning `0` to `num % i`, which is not possible as you can only assign a value to a **variable** and not an expression.

You want to **test if the expression** equals `0`. For this, you need to use `==` instead of `=`.

Change it to

```
num % i == 0
```

In the line

```
isPrime(i) == True
```

you are testing it correctly.